# Is a Command injection possible in the arg parameter of execve

Tags: c, exec

My program uses excve to run a ls, and the second argument is filled by the user :

```
  char * envp[1] = { 0 };

  execve(my_command, user_input, envp);
```

Is it possible for a user to inject a command in the user_input parameter even though it is considered as an argument?

I tried running this but the $( is interpreted before :

```
./my_program.out "$(cat /etc/passwd)"
```

Is there a way to escape the `$` but still inject the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they can't inject commands unless there is a vulnerability inside ls.

See http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve

> The argument vector and environment can be accessed by the called program's main function, when it is defined as: `int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])`